# setAttribute with no value

Tags: javascript, html, get, setattribute

When you use this:

```
<input id="action" type="hidden" name="">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('action').setAttribute('name','copy'); document.getElementById('myForm').submit()">
```

You get in the URL this:
 `file.php?copy=`

But when you use the normal input, so without setAtrribute:
`<input id="action" type="hidden" name="copy">`

you get this (without '=' sign):
 `file.php?copy`

I know it is a small difference but how can I do this **with** using the setAttribute

Comment: And how would this ever be useful on the serverside in PHP ?

Comment: I'd assume this is more about the `type="hidden"` than about how the `name` attribute was made.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('action').setAttribute('name','copy'); document.getElementById('myForm').submit()">
```

would become:

```
// **BETTER** don't use inline events, but that's a different issue
<button onclick="dosubmit()">

function dosubmit() {
  var destel = document.getElementById('action');
  detel.name = 'name';
  // destel.value = "something"; // to set a value
  el.form..submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference other than potentially one looks "prettier" than the other. However it may interest you that you could have something like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="copy">Click to copy</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Click to delete</button>
```

The server will only receive the `action=copy` or `action=delete` according to the button you clicked.

This method does not rely on JavaScript ;)

Answer (score -1):

I do see the issue you are having. can you show where the issue occurs?

```
<input id="action" type="hidden" name="">
    <button onClick="document.getElementById('action').setAttribute('name','copy'); alert(document.getElementById('action').getAttribute('name'));"> click me </button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g30rg3/ud6zT/